# Show data from several DataSources in the same ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a ListView and two dropdown controllers in the InsertItemTemplate. Those dropdown lists get their data from another  table than the ListViews data.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2"
   DataTextField="Genrename" DataValueField="GenreID" 
   SelectedValue='<%# Bind("GenreID") %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3"
   DataTextField="Directorname" DataValueField="RegissorID"
   SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DirectorID") %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I am adding values to the main ListView, but the values I insert in the main table is ID values like, GenreID.

My table looks something like this:

```
Movie       |    Genre   |    Director
James Bond        3              4
Donald Duck       6              13
The Hangover      7              8
```

Now, i want to display the Names of the Genre and Director instead of the ID's, but i still need to insert the ID's inte my main table (movies).

This is how my ItemTemplate looks like:

```
<td>
   <asp:Label ID="GenreIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GenreID") %>' />
</td>
<td>
   <asp:Label ID="RegissorIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RegissorID") %>' />
</td>
```

Comment: it depends on how do you access data: ADO .Net, some ORM?

Comment: I access the data with ADO.net, i get the data from a List

Comment: Do a join in the query itself that is being accessed by the drop downs.

Comment: It looks like you've done what you're asking for. You want to display names and send ids to the database right? I can see your dropdownlists are doing so.

Comment: @nuux Exactly, and I want the ID to be in my movie table, but when i display all the values in my GridView i want to see the real names instead of the ID's for example 'Comedy' not it's ID '4'. But as i said i want the ID 4 too be in the movie table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the `SelectCommand` of the datasource control that is being accessed by the ListView.
`Join the three tables`

Example:

```
 SelectCommand="Select m.movie,m.Genre,m.Director,g.GenreName,d.DirectorName From Movies as m Inner Join Genres as g ON m.Genre=g.GenreID Inner Join Directors as d ON m.Director=d.DirectorID"
```

After this point `GenreName` and `DirectorName` are accessible to your gridview.
Update your ItemTemplate

```
 <td>
  <asp:Label ID="GenreIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GenreName") %>' />
</td>
<td>
 <asp:Label ID="RegissorIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DirectorName") %>' />
</td>
```

**Edit**
I saw in your comment that you're getting the data from a list. I guess it works the same just update your select statement. In my example I assumed you're using SqlDataSource control